# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'data_format') CoreML/Xcode

Tags: python, keras, typeerror, coreml

I am attempting to modify this tutorial to work with my own dataset/model:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/04/23/running-keras-models-on-ios-with-coreml/

However, when I try to take the model that I have serialized and convert it to a .mlmodel for Xcode by running the **coremlconverter.py** script:

```
# USAGE
# python coremlconverter.py --model pokedex.model --labelbin lb.pickle

# import necessary packages
from keras.models import load_model
import coremltools
import argparse
import pickle

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to trained model model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--labelbin", required=True, help="path to label binarizer")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the class labels
print("[INFO] loading class labels from label binarizer")
lb = pickle.loads(open(args["labelbin"], "rb").read())
class_labels = lb.classes_.tolist()
print("[INFO] class labels: {}".format(class_labels))

# load the trained convolutional neural network
print("[INFO] loading model...")
model = load_model(args["model"])

# convert the model to coreml format
print("[INFO] converting model")
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
input_names="image",
image_input_names="image",
image_scale=1/255.0,
class_labels=class_labels,
is_bgr=True)

# save the model to disk
output = args["model"].rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".mlmodel"
print("[INFO] saving model as {}".format(output))
coreml_model.save(output)
```

I end up with the following traceback/error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "coremlconverter.py", line 26, in <module> model = load_model(args["model"])
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 243, in load_model
model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 317, in model_from_config
return layer_module.deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
printable_module_name='layer')
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 143, in deserialize_keras_object
list(custom_objects.items())))
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1352, in from_config
layer = layer_module.deserialize(conf, custom_objects=custom_objects)
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
printable_module_name='layer')
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
return cls.from_config(config['config'])
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1269, in from_config
return cls(**config)
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 483, in __init__
super(Flatten, self).__init__(**kwargs)
File "/Users/fraser/.virtualenvs/keras_tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 292, in __init__
raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'data_format')
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error because my trained model has the exact same architecture as the one in the tutorial.  All I've done is change the number of class labels.

Any advice on where/why this is failing, and how to go about fixing it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I have come to realise that the problem lies with the version of tensorflow/keras that I am using for the serialization; I had to downgrade to a lower version in order to write it to the .mlmodel file without an error.

Comment: Which versions did you end up using?

Comment: I believe that I ended up using Keras 2.1.3/ Tensorflow 1.8.0.  Hope that helps!